# Enforcing user quota in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

What is the best way to enforce per-user quota on data stored in Firebase?

My users will be able to create documents with a unique id on the following path:

/documents/id/contents

The id will be uniquely generated using a transaction. The id will be reserved by using a verification rule (`contents.id == auth.id`)

However how do I prevent a user from spamming the db (by randomly allocating ids to themselves)? Can I have a rule which counts the number of ids allocated to a user and rejects them if the count is too high?

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no good way to do this.

In some cases you could fully enumerate the children that are allowed to exist (child1, child2, etc), and grant read / write for each one. This won't work for large numbers though or for ids you don't know beforehand.

We do have plans to built features to restrict the number of allowed children and to provide other features to enforce quotas on users.

Comment: Until the quota is implemented, does firebase enforce a quota restriction on an app's db? Is it possible for one malicious user to bring down the whole service?

Comment: No, we don't enforce quotas. You can grow your Firebase as large as you want. We do monitor things pretty carefully though. If someone tries to DDoS us or otherwise attach us we'll handle them.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your responses. While I appreciate the efforts of Firebase, the current approach is just a cure; prevention would be better. I hope you implement per-user quota capabilities soon. The ideal would be to allow the admin to define a custom function for limiting the quota. An efficient count query would be very useful.